# No persistence provider

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee, wildfly

I am trying to run a very basic JPA example on Wildfly. 
This is the structure of my project:

[image]

Person and Project are two JPA entities.
This is the content of my persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="testJpa">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider> 
        <class>entities.Person</class>
        <class>entities.Project</class>

        <properties>
         <property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="Derby"/>  
         <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/JPADB"/>
         <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="user"/>
         <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="pwd"/>
         <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"/>
         <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINE"/>
         <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>
        </properties>



   </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Tables are correctly generated from the entity classes so I know the persistence.xml is valid.

I am trying to create an entity in the CreatePerson class, like this:

```
public class CreatePerson {

   public static void main( String[ ] args ) {

      EntityManagerFactory emfactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("testJpa");

      EntityManager entitymanager = emfactory.createEntityManager( );
      entitymanager.getTransaction( ).begin( );

      Person usr = new Person( ); 
      usr.setName("Bob");

      entitymanager.persist( usr );
      entitymanager.getTransaction( ).commit( );

      entitymanager.close( );
      emfactory.close( );
   }
}
```

I get the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named testJpa
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:61)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
    at services.CreatePerson.main(CreatePerson.java:11)
```

Comment: How do you build your application? With maven and target war? Which dependency scope do you use? Provided? If so, are you sure that Wildfly has the eclipselink dependencies in his classpath?

Answer (score 0):

It is totally unclear what are you doing. Wildfly is an JavaEE application server, but I see JavaSE class **public static void main**.

You should create JavaEE project (for Eclipse, as far as I know you need to download [Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/europawinter) ) then probably create DAO EJB, inject **EntityManager** in it with

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "puName")
private EntityManager em;
```

then you code should work

```
Person usr = new Person("blabla"); 
em.persist(usr)
```

IMHO, you should look for another tutorial.